# Python list inside string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string: '[1, 2, 3]'
I want to convert it to: [1, 2, 3]

I know there was a single bif that I could use, but I couldn't find it or for the life of me recall what it was.

I know someone out there remembers, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To process a string as if were code:

```
>>> eval('[1, 2, 3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `eval` might be a big security hole in your application. At least use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Agreed, but it is the simplest, if you assume trusted input.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just couldn't remember the exact keyword.